# Como converter um valor no tipo UNIX Timestamp para o DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, conversão-de-tipo, timestamp

Como converter um valor no tipo `UNIX timestamp (seconds since 1970)`, exemplo ***1396148400***, em um `DateTime`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma forma de tratar unix timestamp;

```
string start = "1396148900"; // o teu exemplo;
 // Criar equivalente Datetime > UNIX Epoch. (seconds since 1970)
 DateTime dtIni = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

 // adicionar o nº de segundos  UNIX timestamp para comversão;
 dtIni = dateTime.AddSeconds(double.Parse(start));
```